# jQuery UI Autocomplete combo doesn't work in my wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete in my theme and I already try at jsfiddle and it worked. I'm pretty sure I was loaded necessary scripts in my theme. But still didn't work. How should I do it? Working jQuery UI default demo click [here](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check java conflict issue first with firefox .
download firebug then check
check there should't be any js file repeat
f.e  .min file

Comment: K then try all plugin disable 1 by 1 and check , Some time plugin creates some issue with java script .